# Play 2.4.6, configuring build settings for bytecode enhancement in tests

Tags: java, testing, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play framework 2.4.6 with Ebean and Java.

When I run my tests, I cannot set the value of any field. I think the bytecode enhancement (automatic getter/setter generation) doesn't work.

My test (keep calm, the framework is supposed to put the getter/setter for "name"):

```
    @Test
    public void createAndUpdate() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Usuario newUser = new Usuario("bob@gmail.com", "secret", "Spongebob Squarepants");
                newUser.save();

                Usuario alterUser = Usuario.find.where().eq("email", "bob@gmail.com").findUnique();
                alterUser.name = "another name";
                alterUser.update();

                Usuario bob = Usuario.find.where().eq("email", "bob@gmail.com").findUnique();

                assertNotNull(bob);
                assertEquals("another name", bob.name);
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried using `save()` instead of `update()` with no desired results.

The test fails; output:

```
[error] Test IntegrationTest.createAndUpdate failed: expected:<[another name]> but was:<[Spongebob Squarepants]>, took 0.228 sec
```

I've read that Play bytecode enhancement doesn't work for the code into the "test" directory. According to this post https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/fRHXLZi0J1c/CS8b8XBNS3UJ, I need to configure the `buid.scala` file like this https://gist.github.com/joelso/3496872

The post is for the version 2.0.x so it uses the `build.scala` file, but for 2.4.x the build settings are into `build.sbt` and I haven't achieved to load it without errors.

The question is, How can I configure the build settings file to work as the above post states but using the new `build.sbt` style?

I also tried to use the old `build.scala` only, but it gives me errors in every line.

I'm aware that the easiest solution is to manually put the getters/setters, but I'd like to try using the Play style.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

According to the documentation, my class has public, non static, non final fields. It has got only one public static field for getting a `Finder` object and make queries. The field in my class is just like in the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean#Using-Model-superclass
I even tried using a method instead of that static field, but it didn't make any difference.

This is the "Usuario" class. I tried changing the "find" static field for a method, but the result was the same.

```
@Entity
public class Usuario extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String name;
    public boolean esAdmin;

    public Usuario(String email, String password, String name) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.esAdmin = false;
    }



    public static Find<Long, Usuario> find = new Find<Long, Usuario>() {};
}
```

Comment: Except for you `find` declaration, which I change to be `static` to pass compilation, everything works as expected to me. Which database are you using? How is your `ebean.default` configuration (at `conf/application.conf` file)?

Comment: sorry, the find field was static since the beginning. I made a mistake, but I'll edit the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both references that you post are very outdated. You should [see how to use the enhancer here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlayEnhancer). Special attention to the section about[how to setup](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlayEnhancer#Setting-up). Also, there are some constraints when using it:

> The enhancer looks for all fields on Java classes that:
>
> - are public
> - are non static
> - are non final
>
> For each of those fields, it will generate a getter and a setter if they don’t already exist. If you wish to provide a custom getter or setter for a field, this can be done by just writing it, the Play enhancer will simply skip the generation of the getter or setter if it already exists.

So, check if the properties at class `Usuario` satisfies there conditions.

**After your edit:**

I've changed your `find` declaration to the following line:

```
public static Find<Long, Usuario> find = new Finder<>(Usuario.class);
```

Everything worked as expected. I also have the following configuration at `conf/application.conf`:

```
ebean.default=["models.*"]
```

This is the content of `build.sbt`:

```
name := """test"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v", "-q")
```

And the content for `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")
```

Comment: Thank you. I've checked my class. It is just like the documentation states, except for a static field used to access the Finder instance (but I took that field's code from the Play guide).

Comment: And is it working? If not, please, post the code for Usuario class.

Comment: unfortunately, is not working. The class was already like the documentation says.

Comment: Please, post the code so we can see if it is related to enhancement or not.

Comment: Almost all my configuration was like yours. Only `testOptions` in `build.sbt` was missing; but my test is still failing :( I have some extra configuration to make it work in Eclipse. To be sure, I'll create a new clean project and I'll try again.

Comment: Finally worked! I first put my tests and classes into a new project and worked right. Then I realized that, in the old project, the version of the plugin `sbt-play-ebean` was 1.0.0 not 2.0.0. So I changed the version, but it didn't work until I called `clean`, `update` and `reload` commands in the activator console (I think only `clean` was necessary); then all my tests passed. Thank you very much.